# Write your answer in simplest

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify: sqrt(2009*2011*2015*2017+36)+10. Write your answer in simplest form
[image]

Comment: One might expect that the expression under the root is a square. It is.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\displaystyle\frac{2009+2011+2015+2017}4=2013=a$

$\displaystyle\implies 2009\cdot2011\cdot2015\cdot2017=(a-4)(a-2)(a+2)(a+4)$
$\displaystyle=(a^2-16)(a^2-4)=a^4-20a^2+64$

Now, $\displaystyle 2009\cdot2011\cdot2015\cdot2017+36$
$\displaystyle=a^4-20a^2+64+36=(a^2)^2+10^2-2\cdot a^2\cdot10=(a^2-10)^2$

Comment: Sometimes playing with algebra proves to be more handy

Comment: This is from Diophantus's playbook - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Use the identity  $\ 4XY = (X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2\ $ to rewrite the radicand as a square

$$4\, \overbrace{(n\!+\!a)(n\!+\!b)}^{X}\ \overbrace{n(n\!+\!a\!+\!b)}^Y\,+\!\overbrace{(ab)^2}^{(X\,-\,Y)^2}\! =\, \overbrace{(2n^2\!+2(a\!+\!b)n\!+\!ab)^2}^{(X\,+\,Y)^2}$$

Yours is special case $\ n,a,b,c = 2009,2,6,8\ $ (and divide the above by $\,4 = 2^2).$